# Unable to locate element and TimeoutException when WebDriverWait is used

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to automate the clicking of the "SHOW MORE" button at the bottom of the page to get all the reviews there is.

However, I'm having some problems locating it and would really appreciate it if you could help me out.

I have tried a couple of methods but I am not sure why none of them work.

1) Method 1: CSS Selector

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("U26fgb.O0WRkf.oG5Srb.C0oVfc.n9lfJ.M9Bg4d")
```

leads to:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

2) Method 2 : XPath Helper (an extension on Chrome)

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body[@id='yDmH0d']/div[@id='fcxH9b']/div[@class='WpDbMd']/c-wiz[@class='zQTmif SSPGKf I3xX3c drrice']/div[@class='T4LgNb']/div[@class='ZfcPIb']/div[@class='UTg3hd']/div[@class='JNury Ekdcne']/div[@class='LXrl4c']/div/div[@class='W4P4ne ']/div[2]/div[@class='PFAhAf']/div[@class='U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb C0oVfc n9lfJ']/span[@class='CwaK9']/span[@class='RveJvd snByac']")
```

leads to the same error as above.

3) Method 3 : WebDriverWait

I read the other stack overflow questions related to this and tried using WebDriverWait and here is my code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body[@id='yDmH0d']/div[@id='fcxH9b']/div[@class='WpDbMd']/c-wiz[@class='zQTmif SSPGKf  I3xX3c drrice']/div[@class='T4LgNb']/div[@class='ZfcPIb']/div[@class='UTg3hd']/div[@class='JNury Ekdcne']/div[@class='LXrl4c']/div/div[@class='W4P4ne ']/div[2]/div[@class='zc7KVe']/div[@class='d15Mdf bAhLNe']/div[@class='xKpxId zc7KVe']/div[@class='bAhLNe kx8XBd']/span[@class='X43Kjb']"))).click()
```

but was faced with TimeoutException

4) I came across another question on changing frames when faced with such errors but it seems like I don't have a frame to switch to (Do correct me if I'm wrong)

This is the url of the page: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Daylight.EzLinkAndroid&hl=en_SG

The HTML that I have problems with is as follows:

```
<div class="PFAhAf" jscontroller="XO1Ihd" jsaction="JIbuQc:bRsdTc(i3y3Ic);">
      <div role="button" class="U26fgb O0WRkf oG5Srb C0oVfc n9lfJ M9Bg4d 
         j7nIZb" jscontroller="VXdfxd" jsaction="click:cOuCgd; 
         mousedown:UX7yZ; mouseup:lbsD7e; mouseenter:tfO1Yc; 
         mouseleave:JywGue; focus:AHmuwe; blur:O22p3e; 
         contextmenu:mg9Pef;touchstart:p6p2H; touchmove:FwuNnf; 
         touchend:yfqBxc(preventMouseEvents=true|preventDefault=true); 
         touchcancel:JMtRjd;j9grLe:.CLIENT;HUObcd:.CLIENT" jsshadow="" 
         jsname="i3y3Ic" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0">
               <div class="Vwe4Vb MbhUzd" jsname="ksKsZd" style="top: 17.2px; 
                     left: 70.225px; width: 98px; height: 98px;"></div>
               <div class="ZFr60d CeoRYc"></div><span jsslot="" class="CwaK9"> 
             <span class="RveJvd snByac">Show more</span>
             </span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Sorry for the long post and thank you for your help! :)

Comment: The link you have shared doesn't have any element with text Show more. Make sure that the element is present on the page.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Scroll to the bottom of this link until you see the "SHOW MORE" button. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Daylight.EzLinkAndroid&hl=en_SG&showAllReviews=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `yDmH0d`, `fcxH9b`, etc. seems to be dynamically generated and change each time you load/reload the page. The only thing which doesn't change is [`span`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)  tag text.

So I would recommend using the following simple selector:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Show more']"))).click()
```

[image]

Also consider using [Page Object Model](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Design+Patterns+-+Page+Object+Model) design pattern, it will make your life easier when it comes to test support when/where UI changes and lets you write tests much faster.

See [Page Objects](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html) page of [Selenium Python documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) for more information if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! It worked :) As i am still pretty new to this, may i know how you realize that yDmH0d, fcxH9b, are dynamically generated?

Comment: Also, i initially thought that clicking of the button would involve the <div role="button" part of the code instead of the one you highlighted. May i know why this is so? I would really appreciate your help on this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As the element is [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` it you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@role='button']//span/span[text()='Show more']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your help but I seem to face the following error when running your code:
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span class="RveJvd snByac">...</span> is not clickable at point (611, 10).